# multiple routing filter in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing, rails-routing

I'm already using :before_filter :authenticate_user! from devise but I would like to add another filter in my controllers after authenticate_user! passes. After the user authenticates I would like to check if some attribute in User is set to true, if not then I would like to redirect the user to some page.

Is there some guide or plugin to create a custom filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another before_filter to your controller. A filter stops the chain if and only if it redirects or renders something, otherwise the next filter is executed.

See more on filters in the RailsGuides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters